# C gets_s() implementation

Tags: c, strings, security, error-handling, io

I'm in a class that is using C, and my instructor has [unfortunately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3019990) used `gets()` in sample code.

As this is obviously a heinous oversight, likely to cause undefined behavior and other various issues (only a little sarcasm), I decided to implement [`gets_s()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897143/3019990), because it was a fun exercise and sometimes it's just not worth it to do full error checking with `fgets()` and you just want to truncate unexpectedly long lines.

I'm not concerned whether this fully implements `gets_s()` as specified in the C11 standard -- this is just supposed to be a drop-in replacement for `gets()` that doesn't overrun your buffer.

However, what is very important is that this function actually does what it advertises: it's safe and doesn't overrun the buffer.

This is my first time working in C (I usually use [java](/questions/tagged/java) or [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin)), and I appreciate all tips, though I'd like at least some mention of the safety of this code, and am also interested in portability (to current compilers).

### `gets_s.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define GETS_S_OK 0
#define GETS_S_ERROR 1
#define GETS_S_OVERRUN 2

static inline int gets_s( char str[], int n )
{
  char *str_end, *fgets_return;
  int temp;

  fgets_return = fgets( str, n, stdin );

  /* If fgets fails, it returns NULL.
  This includes the case where stdin is exhausted. */
  if ( fgets_return == NULL )
  {
    str[0] = '\0';
    return GETS_S_ERROR;
  }

  str_end = str + strlen(str) - 1;

  if ( str_end == '\n' )
  {
    *str_end = '\0';
    return GETS_S_OK;
  }

  temp = fgetc( stdin );
  if (temp == EOF || temp = '\n')
    return GETS_S_OK;

  do temp = fgetc( stdin );
  while ( temp != EOF && temp != '\n' );

  return GETS_S_OVERRUN;
}
```

and a small test file:

### `gets_s.c`

```
#include "gets_s.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char buffer[10];
  int gets_s_return;

  printf("Enter up to %d characters safely.\n", sizeof(buffer) - 1);

  gets_s_return = gets_s( buffer, sizeof(buffer) );

  printf("buffer = %s", buffer);
  printf("gets_s return = %d", gets_s_return);

  return 0;
}
```

It compiles successfully with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror gets_s.c`, so that's a plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't call it `gets_s` as the signature and behavior differs in some subtle and not-so-subtle ways, that just leads to confusion and frustration. Anyway, you *really* wouldn't want the `gets_s`-contract.
Call it something descriptive like `getline_truncated`.

Do you know that `n <= 0` is UB in your implementation?

```
if (temp == EOF || temp = '\n')
                        ^
```

I'm sure your compiler warns you about the typo above.
Or don't you ask it for all warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -std=...`)?

I suggest re-defining and re-naming your return-codes to allow better result-testing:

```
#define GETS_S_TRUNCATED 1
// Because truncation is not neccessarily an error
#define GETS_S_OK 0
#define GETS_S_ERROR EOF
// Because we already have an appropriate negative constant
```

This way you can test for `==0` or `>=0` depending on what you decide is "success", respectively `!=0` or `<0` for "failure".

Comment: The `temp = "\n"` is a typo in this post only; I originally wrote the code on a separate machine then retyped it for the question. I'm sure had it been part of my code it would have errored (as I compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror`.

Comment: @CAD97 This is why many C programmers who value correctness and security would have written `'\n' == temp` -- that way, if they typo `==` to `=`, you get a much more definite error

Answer (score 1):

- The code may read too much:

  ```
      temp = fgetc( stdin );
      if (temp == EOF || temp = '\n')
          return GETS_S_OK;
  ```

  If `temp` is neither `EOF` nor `\n`, the character is lost. You'd better `ungetc()` it.
- The code oversteps the mandate. The loop

  ```
      do temp = fgetc( stdin );
      while ( temp != EOF && temp != '\n' );
  ```

  guarantees that the caller will never see an empty string. Sometimes empty strings are semantically meaningful.
- `man fgets`:

  > The fgets() and gets() functions do not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.

  You are in a great position to do just that. Instead of blindly returning `GETS_S_ERROR`, determine what happened, and return accordingly. E.g. `#define GETS_S_EOF 3`.

Comment: I'm mimicking `gets()` in that I'm reading to the end of the line, the idea being that that's what someone who would have used `gets()` wants. If you want the stop-at-n-minus-one-characters behavior, just use `fgets()`. Or at least, that was my reason for picking that behavior. (If you want to say I'm reading too much, say why you would pick that behavior explicitly. I chose to continue reading to mimic `gets()` if it didn't write past your buffer.)

Comment: @CAD97 I understand that your objection addresses my first bullet point. Your code indeed mimics `gets`, and it indeed doesn't overflow the buffer. My point is that `gets` is broken in more than one way. `getline` more or less solves them all.